# How to count no of rows of a table in codeigniter and display in view with other details?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello everyone i have a problem please help me

I have two table one is **Subject** and other is **question**

fields in Subject table is

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
| id   | name      | set_id    |   
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

in Question table

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| id   |question         | answer         | subject        |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

I want to display details like below image
[image]

How to do this please help me your help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the filed inside 2 table?

Comment: show us the table structure and your effort thus far.

Comment: edited the question please review.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Problem has been solved now.

Comment: Have you tried using foreach loop to iterate through the array values retreived...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function subjectlist(){
  $val=array('a.id','a.name','a.set_id','b.set_name');
  $where=array('user_id'=>$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);
  $sub=$this->login->get_join($val,'','b.id=a.set_id',$where,'subject as a','q_set as b');
  $count_all=array();

  foreach($sub as $count) {
    $where1=array('subject_id'=>$count->id);
    $count_all[]=array('id'=>$count->id,'name'=>$count->name,'set_id'=>$count->set_id,'set_name'=>$count->set_name,'all_val'=>$this->login->count_val($where1,'question'));
  }
  $data['subject']=$count_all;
  $this->load->view('i_user/subject_list',$data);
}
```